# How can i multiplicate an object in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist with 2 objects inside and i Need muiltplicate N times the last of them.
Exemple.

```
Arraylist = [Z0123,Z0321]
```

I need this result

```
ArrayList = [Z0123,Z0321,Z0321,Z0321,N...]
```

I'm trying with the last element, but this dosn't work with N elements

```
    for(int i = 0; i < statusCorrigido.size(); i++) {
        int tamanho = statusCorrigido.size()-1 ;
        listaFinal.add(statusCorrigido.get(i));
        listaFinal.add(statusCorrigido.get(tamanho));
    }
```

Comment: You'd probably want to first iterate to the list's and add all elements except the last one and then have another loop which iterates N times and adds the list's last element each of those times.

Comment: Exactly, but in this way, I need the first and second elements anyway... i can't separate them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `addAll` with `Collections.nCopies`.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Z0123", "Z0321"));
int n = 5;
list.addAll(Collections.nCopies(n - 1, list.get(list.size() - 1)));
System.out.println(list); // [Z0123, Z0321, Z0321, Z0321, Z0321, Z0321]
```

Comment: Nice! I'm going to try

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, oh. I know hehe, sorry for this. 

this didn't work well.. the result to me  was [z0321,z0321,z0321,z0321] N times

Comment: @WillianLima I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: @WillianLima If you check this [demo](https://ideone.com/sfRKsT) you can see that my example works.

Comment: This works! I made a mistake when i was writing xD

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the list while looping throught it!
Firstly get the last item and then add it to the list.

```
Object copy = list.get(list.size() - 1);
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   list.add(copy)
```

Comment: I tried this way, but didn't work how i espected

Comment: Sorry, I edited the bugs, it should be fine and simple by now

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively, see i'll show you how:

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    array.add(5);
    array.add(2);
    System.out.println(addElement(5, array));
  } 
  public static ArrayList addElement(int stopCondition, ArrayList array){
    if (stopCondition == 0){
        return array;
    }
    array.add(array.get(array.size()-1));
    stopCondition--;
    return addElement(stopCondition, array);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```